# Exporting data from Wolfram Cloud

Tags: export, data, wolfram-cloud

I have this table:

```
data = Table[{x, y, Sqrt[r^2-x^2-y^2]-r+RandomReal[{0,0.005}]}, {x, 0, 2.5,0.5}, {y, 0, 2.5,0.5}];
```

How can I export it to a .txt file using Wolfram Cloud? Preferably in such a way that I can import it back and do further manipulations if I need to.

Comment: Is it essential that you have it as a TXT file or do you simply want to be able to export it and then re-import it?  If you are just looking to have it cloud accessible, you simply have to use `CloudPut` and `CloudGet`.

Comment: A txt file would be preferable so I can use the data in other softwares as well.

Comment: One issue you might run into is how Mathematica notates square roots.  The cleanest approach might be to export it to a local TXT then copy that file to the cloud:  `CopyFile[Export["data.txt", data], CloudObject["data.txt"]]`.  Then bring it back in: `ToExpression@
 Import["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/YOUR.NAME/data.txt"]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As already suggested above, using `Export` followed by `CopyFile` to a `CloudObject` certainly works.

You can also `Export` directly to a `CloudObject`, or (even more concisely) use `CloudExport`. In terms of the format, you might consider "CVS" instead of "TXT". Then this would become:

```
CloudExport[data, "CSV", "data.csv"]
```

To bring it back into WL, you would use `CloudImport["data.csv"]`. The entries in the table will be raw strings, so you could apply `ToExpression` to them to turn them into WL expressions. You should only do that if you trust the data, though, since it would execute arbitrary expressions. The third argument to `ToExpression` could be useful, where you could provide `Hold` to avoid immediate evaluation of each item.

If you're only dealing with "simple enough" expressions, you could also use `Interpreter["Expression"]`, which allows evaluation of simple expressions but does not allow other side effects such as accessing the file system (see the [Expression interpreter type documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/interpreter/Expression.html) for more details). So you would use

```
Map[Interpreter["Expression"], CloudImport["data.csv"], {2}]
```

to turn each entry in the two-dimensional table into an expression.